# Distribute dataset evenly by range of id in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, partition, evenly

I'm very new to PySpark and been having a challenge with partitioning data.

I have 2 datasets:

- Ad data set (very big) with ad_id and some attribute columns
- Ad transactions data set (smaller), includes ad_id and transaction date

It appears to me that i can only partition by ad_id, my question is:
how can i evenly distribute data by the ranges of ad_id for both data set, so that when i need to compute a join between the 2 sets, it'll be faster?

here is what i'm trying to do:

```
ads.write.partitionBy("ad_id").mode('overwrite').parquet(os.path.join(output_data, 'ads_table'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Bucketing

If you are using spark v2.3 and greater, you can use **bucketing** to avoid the shuffle that takes place on the join after the write.

With bucketing you can put your data into buckets based on a column (usually the one you are joining on). Then when spark reads the data from the buckets again, you will not need to perform an exchange.

#### 1. Sample Data

**Transactions (Fact)**

```py
t1.sample(n=5)

ad_id     impressions
30        528749
1         552233
30        24298
30        311914
60        41661
```

**Names (Dimension)**

```py
t2.sample(n=5)

ad_id     brand_name
1         McDonalds
30        McDonalds
30        Coca-Cola
1         Coca-Cola
30        Levis
```

#### 2. Disable Broadcast Join

Since one table is large and the other is small, you will need to disable `broadcastJoin`.

```py
sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1")
```

#### 3. Without Bucketing

```py
t = spark.createDataFrame(t1)
b = spark.createDataFrame(t2)


t.write.saveAsTable('unbucketed_transactions')
b.write.saveAsTable('unbucketed_brands')

unbucketed_transactions = sqlContext.table("unbucketed_transactions")
unbucketed_brands = sqlContext.table("unbucketed_brands")


unbucketed_transactions.join(unbucketed_brands, 'ad_id').explain()



+- Project [ad_id#1842L, impressions#1843L, brand_name#1847]
   +- SortMergeJoin [ad_id#1842L], [ad_id#1846L], Inner
      :- Sort [ad_id#1842L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(ad_id#1842L, 200), true, [id=#1336]     <-- 0_0
      :     +- Project [ad_id#1842L, impressions#1843L]
      :        +- Filter isnotnull(ad_id#1842L)
      :           +- FileScan parquet default.unbucketed_transactions
      +- Sort [ad_id#1846L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(ad_id#1846L, 200), true, [id=#1337]     <-- 0_0 
            +- Project [ad_id#1846L, brand_name#1847]
               +- Filter isnotnull(ad_id#1846L)
                  +- FileScan parquet default.unbucketed_brands
```

As you can see there is an exchange that takes place due to the unbucketed join.

#### 4. With Bucketing

```py
# The number 30 tells spark how large the buckets should be. 
# The second parameter is what column the bucket should be based on.

unbucketed_transactions.write \
.bucketBy(30,'ad_id') \
.sortBy('ad_id') \
.saveAsTable('bucketed_transactions')


unbucketed_brands.write \
.bucketBy(30,'ad_id') \
.sortBy('ad_id') \
.saveAsTable('bucketed_brands')

transactions = sqlContext.table("bucketed_transactions")
brands = sqlContext.table("bucketed_brands")

transactions.join(brands, 'ad_id').explain()


+- Project [ad_id#1867L, impressions#1868L, brand_name#1872]
   +- SortMergeJoin [ad_id#1867L], [ad_id#1871L], Inner
      :- Sort [ad_id#1867L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Project [ad_id#1867L, impressions#1868L]
      :     +- Filter isnotnull(ad_id#1867L)
      :        +- FileScan parquet default.bucketed_transactions
      +- Sort [ad_id#1871L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Project [ad_id#1871L, brand_name#1872]
            +- Filter isnotnull(ad_id#1871L)
               +- FileScan parquet default.bucketed_brands
```

As can be seen by the plan above, there are no more exchanges that take place.
Thus, you will improve your performance, by avoiding the exchange.

Comment: thank you so much. i've applied the settings as you specified above and it works well for me! appreciate your help!

Comment: No Problme @DanPham! Happy to help!